# Search with multiple criteria in LIKE query

Tags: sql

I have a problem when I work with SQL query. I have 2 table `Student` and `Class`, and I want to search by both student name, student id, class name, ...

If I write SQL Query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Student,Class
WHERE Student.classname = Class.classname 
AND student_name LIKE '%ab%' OR class_name LIKE '%ab%'
```

It works well! But when I change `%ab%` part to `?` to store value of textbox like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Student,Class 
WHERE Student.classname = Class.classname 
AND student_name LIKE ? OR class_name LIKE ?
```

It doesn't work and can not do anything. So, what can I do to compare multiple criteria with one input text in SQL?

Comment: `?` is a placeholder for a parameter.  How are you trying to pass those parameters? You've failed to provide enough information here. It certainly works when you do it correctly, but you've not given us the information needed to explain why it's not working for you or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what framework or tool you are using with your SQL, but given the following `LIKE` expression:

```sql
student_name LIKE ? OR class_name LIKE ?
```

if you wanted to find students or classes containing `ab`, then you would bind `%ab%` to both `?` placeholders.  You would do this from the tool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to have, but I guess you would like to declare a variable as one input?

```
Declare @input varchar(20)  
Set @input = '%ab%'

SELECT * FROM Student,Class
WHERE Student.classname = Class.classname 
AND student_name LIKE @input OR class_name LIKE @input
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use LIKE. Instead, use a regular expression.

There are only two benefits of LIKE:

1. under some circumstances, it is indexable, (your query is not)
   and
2. LIKE is part of the standard, while regexps are DBMS dependent